# PHP/Smarty Nested array from DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Ok guys I am trying to access a php/mysql db via a nested query.

eg. I have 2 tables 1) persons and 2) registration. I have a refferal id tab in registrations. So when a user logs in he should be able to see 4 levels of registrations done below his id.

Table structure

Registration
id | Registration ID |  regtype |  Upline ID |  uid |FirstName |MiddleName | LastName Last etc

personal

id| uid | upline | fname | miname | lname | etc and lot of other details

Now i am doing it like this to get to the first level.

```
$tid=$_GET['tid'];
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else
{  
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM personal WHERE id=$tid ");
$counta = mysql_num_rows($resulta);
while ($rowa = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulta)) {
$selid=$rowa['uid'];
$amount=$rowa['amountf'];
$plan=$rowa['planname'];
$resultfulla[] = $rowa;
}
$resultb = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM regtab WHERE regtab.upline=$selid " );
$countb = mysql_num_rows($resultb);
$rowz=array();
while ($rowb = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultb)) {
$rowz[] = $rowb;
}
```

Now i am able to get to one level but how do i cycle the second array and the arrays that will be produced later to get a tree structure. Or so....any help....

With the array rowz i am able to store the results of the 1st line regstration that i have done. Now using this array i need to find out how to get the second line registrations that have been done below array rowz.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join your queries and get the result.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM personal 
        LEFT JOIN regtab ON regtab.upline = personal.uid
        WHERE personal .id=".$tid;
```

Get all the results in php.

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, accept it, others may find it useful, who gets same issue.

Comment: +1 from me ;-)  Hopefully an accept to come across from over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542880/parent-child-relationship-within-a-single-table)...