# Parent - Child relationship within a single table

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child

I have a table which is like the following.

```
parentid   uid
10001      10001
10001      10002
10001      10003
10002      10004
10004      10005
10003      10006
10005      10007
```

I need to establish the parent child relationship between rows in this single table.

I need to get the parent in the reverse order **till 4 levels**. For example the last record is **uid 10007** whose **parentid is 10005**.  Now **uid 10005**'s parent is **10004** and **10004**'s parent is **10002** and **10002**'s parent is **10001**.

I am using MySQL so recursion seems to be not possible. What are the options that I have and how do I address this multi-level issue. I use PHP/MySQL.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a finite 4 levels, you shouldn't need recursion (although it'd be handy to be able to use eg MS SQL CTEs).

Something like:

```
SELECT
  t4.uid as child, 
  --t3.uid as parent,
  --t2.uid as grand_parent,
  --t1.uid as great_grand_parent,
  t1.parentid as great_great_grand_parent
FROM
  your_table_name t1

  inner join your_table_name t2
  on t2.parentid = t1.uid

  inner join your_table_name t3
  on t3.parentid = t2.uid

  inner join your_table_name t4
  on t4.parentid = t3.uin

where 
  t4.uid = '10007' -- your start node.
```

If you need to do this for multiple nodes, you'd need to join this to something that selects your start nodes, or eg replace the above `WHERE t4.uid = '10007'` clause to be `WHERE t4.uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM your_table_name)`

This was done freehand so apologies for typos.

Comment: Sepster Thanx a ton. This worked. Now if i want to reverse the query then how should i Do that. I need to find the children and there children and so on till 4 levels. I am working on it as of now but still....Thanx in advance...

Comment: @DarthVader easiest way would be to simply change the `WHERE t4.uid = '10007'` to `WHERE t1.uid = '10001'`. I think*. Although those column names I put in might no longer apply. I think*. *I'm tired...

Comment: @DarthVader If I had time I'd look at it properly for you, but the core is already there for you to re-jig once you get your head around how it works. Hey you should up-vote anything you find useful, and accept the answer that solves your problem.  We do this for the love (and for the rep points!). I also noticed you've asked a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244227/php-smarty-nested-array-from-db) that helped you out, but you haven't voted/accepted that either. Go hard on ticking that one too ;-) Re your earlier thanx, my pleasure mate.

Comment: Hey buddy sepster i tried the voteup but it requires 15 reps mnimum. I only got 11. I will increase it and vote for sure hundred percent...Thanx a ton...

Comment: @DarthVader Ha! No probs champ, thanks for taking the time to accept.  Good luck with it.  Welcome to SO, BTW.

Comment: There you go. I made it to 15 and i have clicked the upvote as well..Thanx a ton see you around...